# How to use aggregate in dataframe of panda when multiple different column is required in the formula

Tags: pandas, dataframe

`data` is in the following format.

```
                              open     high      low    close  volume     vwap
timestamp
2015-02-25 11:05:00+05:30  1410.80  1410.80  1410.10  1410.10      75  1408.23
2015-02-25 11:06:00+05:30  1410.10  1410.95  1410.10  1410.95      44  1408.23
2015-02-25 11:07:00+05:30  1410.95  1410.95  1410.05  1410.05      57  1408.24
2015-02-25 11:08:00+05:30  1410.05  1411.00  1409.10  1410.00     511  1408.26
2015-02-25 11:09:00+05:30  1410.00  1410.05  1410.00  1410.05     176  1408.27
```

Want to convert timeframe.

```
t=data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30min',origin='start')).agg({"open":"first",\
                                                                    "close":"last",\
                                                                    "low":"min",\
                                                                    "high":"max",\
                                                                    "volume":"sum",\
                                                                    "vwap":lambda x: round((x['vwap']*x['volume']).sum()/x['volume'].sum())
                                                                    })
```

Of course, the `vwap` part is wrong, what is the way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If use [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) you can processing each column separately (because performance), so for processing multiple columns use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and then join together by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
g = data.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='30min',origin='start'))
t=g.agg({"open":"first", "close":"last", "low":"min", "high":"max", "volume":"sum"})

f = lambda x: round((x['vwap']*x['volume']).sum()/x['volume'].sum())
t = t.join(g.apply(f).rename('vwap'))
print (t)
                             open    close     low    high  volume  vwap
timestamp                                                               
2015-02-25 11:05:00+05:30  1410.8  1410.05  1409.1  1411.0     863  1408
```

Comment: This gives an error due to `NaN`, as for non-trading hours data is not available which result in `g` multiple `Nan` values.

Comment: @Mr.EU - Can you change data for see problem? Or need `df = df.dropna(how='all')` after my solution?